# Why does my Bing Cognitive Service Request Return a 401?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I just signed up for an Azure free trial and added the Bing Cognitive Service (I want to do image searches). I've gotten the auth key for the service from the Resource Management section of the service, and followed the walkthrough steps in the documentation. Here's a sample request:

`curl "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?safeSearch=Strict&q=Chutes%20and%20Ladders%20game&imageType=Photo" \
     -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <my key from Resource Management>'`

I'm getting a 401 response with the message `Access denied due to invalid subscription key`. Any ideas? Am I using the wrong key?

Here's a visual where I'm getting the key from:

[image: my key source]

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try creating a new instance of the same service and the new keys works. I'm not sure what went wrong with my first one. If MS wants to troubleshoot it I'll keep it around and post any updates here.